# Python telethon forward bot with asyncio functions

Tags: asynchronous, bots, telegram, coroutine, telethon

```
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

# Replace with your own values
api_id = '20xxxxx'
api_hash = 'eddf3exxxxxxxxx'
input_channels = [-1xxxxxx, -10xxxxxx] # input channel IDs
output_channel = -1005xxxxxx # output channel ID

# Create a TelegramClient for connecting to the Telegram API
client = TelegramClient('test', api_id, api_hash)

# Define an event handler that will be called whenever a message is received
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=input_channels))
async def handle_message(event):
    # Forward the message to the output channel
    await client.send_message(output_channel, event.message)


async def main():
    await client.start()
    await client.run_until_disconnected()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I got this error, RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

My attempt, basically, I add main() as a task to the currrent event loop, so it should execute when the event happens i.e. I receive a message

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # asyncio.run(main())
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(main())
```

it returns

<Task pending name='Task-4' coro=<main() running at C:\Users\Tom\TelegramBot\ForwardBotv4.py:28> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001F75C01BA00>()]>>

From what I understood, this means there is already an event loop running on the same thread, so you can only add coroutines to the same event loop and run it. Is there a way I can run a new event loop everytime and destroy the event loop after I close the console? If this is not possible, And how do you run the program on an existing event loop ?

So far, I have no luck getting it to work, to simplify the problem, I also tried running the whole thing without async, but apparently these "client" functions are coroutines.

I'm using Python 3.9.12, Ipython 8.2.0 Spyder Ide console

Answer (score 0):

IPython runs its own `asyncio` event loop, see [Can I use Anaconda/Spyder/IPython with the library?](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/quick-references/faq.html#can-i-use-anaconda-spyder-ipython-with-the-library) in the FAQ ([permalink](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/v1.27.0/readthedocs/quick-references/faq.rst)). You should be able to use `await` directly:

```py
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

...

await client.start()
await client.run_until_disconnected()
```